# Подскажите, как можно сделать чтобы ввод и вывод был в функции ?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как можно сделать чтобы ввод и вывод был в функции ?

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
struct TRAIN {
    string name;
    int number;
    float time;
};
int main() {
    TRAIN train1, train2;
    int num;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Выберите действие: " <<endl<< "1 - Ввод данных" <<endl<< "2 - Вывод данных" <<endl<< "3 - Обработка данных" <<endl<< "4 - Выход" << endl; 
        cin >> num;
        switch(num) {
            case 1: cout <<"Введите данные: "<<endl;
                    cout <<"Пункт назначания: "; cin >>train1.name>>train2.name;
                    cout <<"Номер поезда: "; cin >>train1.number>>train2.number;
                    cout <<"Время отправления: "; cin >>train1.time>>train2.time;
                    break;
            case 2: cout <<"Пункт назначения: "<<train1.name<<endl<<"Номер поезда: "<<train1.number<<endl<<"Время отправления: "<<train1.time<<endl;
                    cout <<"Пункт назначения: "<<train2.name<<endl<<"Номер поезда: "<<train2.number<<endl<<"Время отправления: "<<train2.time<<endl; 
                    break;
            case 3: if (train1.name == train2.name) cout <<"True"<<endl;
                    else cout<<"False"<<endl;
                break;
            case 4: return 0;
            }

        }
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Что значит был в функции?

Comment: Сделайте функцию для ввода и передавайте в нее  train как-то так: Input(&train1, &train2). Внутрь помещайте ваш код из case 1. Для вывода делайте тоже самое, передаете поезд в функцию и переносите в неё код из case 2. Передавайте адрес переменных train1 и train2 так как это структуры.

Comment: Сделать не структуру, а класс, в котором объявить методы ввода и вывода.